# PHP search only showing one result from SQL

Tags: php

Im using a PHP search function on my website and it is currently only displaying one result from my SQL database - i would like it to display all results included in the site_keywords!

Here is the PHP code i'm currently using on my page

```
<?php
mysql_connect("danieljosephdesignsc.ipagemysql.com", "searchdata", "danieljoseph");
mysql_select_db("my_db");

 if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

$search_value = $_GET['value'];

$query = "select * from sites where site_keywords like '%$search_value%'";

$run = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
$title = $row['site_title'];
$link = $row['site_link'];
$desc = $row['site_desc'];
}

}
?>
```

Here is what is included in my body:

```
<?php echo "<div><a href='$link'><h2>$title</h2></a><p>$desc</p><a href='$link'>$link</a></div>";?>
```

Please let me know if you require further info. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How many rows are you getting when you run the query directly in your database?

Comment: Sorry i'm fairly new to PHP/My SQL. How do i run the query directly?

Comment: You are defining your variables in a loop, and the next iteration is overwriting the previous values. You either need to put your html output inside your loop, or save to an array and loop over the array to create the html output.

Comment: Directly in MySQL.  Either in the command line or whatever interface you are using such as the SQL tab of phpMyadmin

Comment: try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` and echo the variables in the `while` loop.

Comment: correction to my comment above. You can use either function, but it still remains that you're not echoing the results inside the `while` loop, as outlined in nomistic's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you aren't echoing the results within your loop.

you need something like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
$title = $row['site_title'];
$link = $row['site_link'];
$desc = $row['site_desc'];
echo "<div><a href='$link'><h2>$title</h2></a><p>$desc</p><a href='$link'>$link</a></div>";
}
```

**Important Note:**

You are using **deprecated code**.  This is true of any function that begins with `mysql_`. This means that your code will no longer work in newer versions of php, and is likely to be *not secure*  if you call any of your variables in your queries.    You really need to look up using ***prepared statements***  using either mysqli or PDO.

[From the official site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_connect()
> PDO::__construct()
> ```

Here's how to use [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
or [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing and it doesn't look as if the OP has seen your answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info... I'll look into this. Really appreciated.

Comment: You'll find that the prepared statements aren't too difficult;  best to learn early in the process, and it will become second nature :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block of code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
$title = $row['site_title'];
$link = $row['site_link'];
$desc = $row['site_desc'];
}
```

Even though you're getting multiple results, each result overwrites the values of the previous one. So in the end you only have a single row. Try saving the results to an array instead and iterating over it in the body.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and help. How would i go about doing this? Are their any good online tutorials?

Comment: *"each result overwrites the values of the previous one"* - OP isn't echoing anything, that's the issue here, not of the "overwriting the previous one(s)". Had OP been using the same variables assignment in the loop, I'd say yes. But the variables are different here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows =array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
     $rows[] =$row;
}
foreach($rows as $row){
    $title = $row['site_title'];
    $link = $row['site_link'];
    $desc = $row['site_desc']; 
   echo "<div><a href='$link'><h2>$title</h2></a><p>$desc</p><a href='$link'>$link</a></div>";

}
```

Comment: Just as an fyi; that first set of code is completely unnecessary.  the while works fine for what the OP is doing.  If he were using PDO, sure, but a foreach is not needed

Comment: right ,foreach is not needed  , but i like this code style